# The Pirate Bay - Secret Message?

Tags: encryption

The Pirate Bay will be relaunched as the timer indicates (see http://thepiratebay.se/)

But on the bottom of the site is a "secret" message. What does this message mean?

It's written in this image: http://thepiratebay.se/aes.png

**Update:**

The timer expired, so here is a screenshot how the site looked like:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is **not** a bittorrent sync key.

As the filename *aes.png* of the "secret message" suggests it's encrypted with AES.
It turned out that a part of the decrypted code is a youtube link -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-YEG9DgRHhA (Arnold Schwarzenegger "I'll Be Back")

But the mystery is not completely solved. In the websites source code there is this line : `<img src="/aes.png" class="pipe vi Makefile" />` It's not clear, what TPB wants us to build.

If you want to replicate the results:

```
echo "JyO7wNzc8xht47QKWohfDVj6Sc2qH+X5tBCT+uetocIJcjQnp/2f1ViEBR+ty0Cz" | openssl aes-128-cbc -K $(printf wearetpb | sha256sum | head -c 32 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]') -nosalt -nopad -iv 0 -base64 -d -p
```

All credits go to dafky2000, who solved it.

Answer (score 8):

[It is a bittorrent sync key](http://www.myce.com/news/the-piratebay-to-continue-using-bittorrent-sync-73965/).

> The mysterious string of characters published on the original The
>   Piratebay domain is a BitTorrent Sync key. With the key it’s possible
>   to gain access to a shared folder containing The Piratebay torrent
>   database.
>
> Yesterday  the original The Piratebay domain thepiratebay.se came
>   alive again. Besides a pirate flag image, hosted by the Isohunt, the
>   site showed the amount of time elapsed since the Swedish police raided
>   the datacenter in Sweden where the Piratebay was (partly) hosted. The
>   site also showed an AES key which according to the Isohunt Twitter
>   account is a BitTorrent Sync key, which allows to share folders.
>
> The folder shared with the key contains all .torrent files of The
>   Piratebay, and a readme file with the text:
>
> > -Place your stuff in the right categories
> >     
> > –Keep the 6 categories that TPB had
> > - Audio, Video, Applications, Games, Porn and Other
> >     
> > –
> >     IRC: http://webchat.freenode.net – #tpbbtsync
> >
> > If they cut off one head, two more shall take it’s place…
> >
> > Hail HYDRA!
>
> The latter refers to a Greek mythological figure we reported about
>   earlier today. The fact that the The Piratebay database is now
>   distributed over Bittorrent Sync might indicate the site will never
>   come back in it’s original form.

Comment: I find it more plausible that HYDRA in this case is a Marvel reference.

Comment: @TerryChia ...which, itself, refers to the Greek mythological figure.

Comment: Which is really spot-on, since the myth goes that two  heads will grow back for every head cut to the Hydra. By "decapitating" TPB database, they have caused a pletora of distributed copies to be spawned

Comment: Also, an AES key is 16, 24 or 32 byte long, which means at most 42 base64 chars + padding, while the string is 50+ chars long. That's certainly not a AES key, that's AES-encrypted data at most.